# Java Currency Converter (How to convert int to Double + Many other issues)

Tags: java, currency

I'm struggling with finding the remainders when converting the currency and then dividing it into dollar amounts. Also, creating a minimum amount of currency to be converted is causing me an issue. I understand alot of my code is a mess but this is my first Java project. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 /* Currency Conversion

 */

 import java.util.Scanner;//to get keyboard input from user

 public class Currency {

/**
 * Converts from a foreign currency to US Dollars.  Takes a
 * deduction for the transaction fee.  Displays how many of
 * each bill and coin denomination the user receives.
 * 
 * @param args no parameters expected
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{


    final double SEK_CONVERSION_RATE = .14;

    /*
     * You'll need a variable or constant for the transaction fee.
     * (3% is fairly typical.)  You'll also need a variable or
     * constant for the minimum transaction fee.
     */
    double transactionFee = .03; 
    final double MIN_TRANSACTION_FEE = 10.00;

    /*
     * You're going to need a variable for the amount of that
     * currency the user wants to convert.
     */

    //Before you can ask the user for input, you need a Scanner so you can read
    //that input:

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    /*
     * Now you're ready to interact with the user.  You'll want
     * to greet them and let them know what currency they can convert
     * and what the rate of exchange is.
     */

    System.out.print("Hello there, welcome to your one and only stop for Swedish Krona conversions. The exchange rate currently sits at .14" );



    /*
     * You should also let them know about the transaction fee.
     */
    System.out.println(" The minimum transaction fee is $10.00 USD.");





    /*
     * Now you're ready to prompt the user for how much money they
     * want to convert.
     */
    System.out.println("How many Swedish Krona would you like to convert to US Dollar?");
    double userCurrencyInput = keyboard.nextDouble();
    /*
     * And then use the Scanner to read in that input and initialize your
     * variable for currency:
     */
    double calculatedCurrInput = (userCurrencyInput*SEK_CONVERSION_RATE);
    /* setting up casting to use later in program */
    int calculatedCurrInputInt = (int) (calculatedCurrInput);



    /*
     * You've received an amount in a foreign currency, but you're going
     * to need the amount in dollars.  Furthermore, you're going to need
     * to know the number of 20's, 10's,5's, 1's, quarters, dimes, nickels
     * and pennies.  And you're going to need to know the transaction fee.
     * These should all be stored in variables.
     */
    double totalTransaction = (userCurrencyInput*transactionFee + calculatedCurrInput);
    int totalTransactionInt = (int) (totalTransaction);



/*Need to define the remainder correct to make change*/
    System.out.println("The conversion is " + calculatedCurrInput); 

    int twentyDollar = 20;
    int twentyDollarBills = calculatedCurrInputInt/twentyDollar;
    int remainderOfTwenty = calculatedCurrInputInt%twentyDollar;

    int tenDollar = 10;
    int tenDollarBills = remainderOfTwenty/tenDollar; 
    int remainderOfTen = remainderOfTwenty%tenDollar;

    int fiveDollar = 5;
    int fiveDollarBills = remainderOfTen/fiveDollar;
    int remainderOfFive = remainderOfTen%fiveDollar; 

    int oneDollar = 1;
    int oneDollarBills = remainderOfFive/oneDollar;
    int remainderOfOnes = remainderOfFive%oneDollar; 
    double remainderOfOnesDBL = (double) remainderOfOnes;

    double quarter = .25;
    double numberOfQuarters = remainderOfOnesDBL/quarter;
    double remainderOfQuarters = remainderOfOnesDBL%quarter;

    double dimes = .10;
    double numberOfDimes = remainderOfQuarters/dimes;
    double remainderOfDimes = remainderOfQuarters%dimes;

    double nickels = .05;
    double numberOfNickels = remainderOfDimes/nickels;
    double remainderOfNickels = remainderOfDimes%nickels;

    double pennies = .01;
    double numberOfPennies = remainderOfNickels/pennies;










    /*
     * Now you're ready to calculate the amount in USD.
     */




    /*
     * Determine what the transaction fee would be, based on the
     * percentage.
     */
    double totalTransactionFee = (userCurrencyInput*transactionFee);
    System.out.println("The transcation fee for your currency exchange would be $" + totalTransactionFee + " US.");


    /*
     * If the transaction fee is less than the minimum transaction
     * fee, you'll need to charge the minimum transaction fee.
     * (Hint, the Math class has min and max methods that receive 
     * two numbers and return either the smaller or larger of those
     * two numbers.)
     */





    /*
     * You'll need to deduct the transaction fee from the total.
     */



    /*
     * Calculate the number of $20's they'll receive
     */




    /*
     * How much is left?
     */


    /*
     * Next do the same for $10's, $5's, etc.
     */
























    /*
     * Finally, let the user know how many dollars their foreign currency
     * converted to, what was deducted for the transaction fee, and how 
     * many of each denomination they are receiving.
     */


    System.out.println("The amount of 20's is " +twentyDollarBills);
    System.out.println("The amount of 10's is " +tenDollarBills);
    System.out.println("The amount of 5's is " +fiveDollarBills);
    System.out.println("The amount of 1's is " +oneDollarBills);
    System.out.println("The amount of quarters is " +numberOfQuarters);
    System.out.println("The amount of dimes is " +numberOfDimes);
    System.out.println("The amount of nickels is " +numberOfNickels);
    System.out.println("The amount of pennies is " +numberOfPennies);






}//end main

}//end Currency
```

Comment: Use `BigDecimal` if you want to handle currency.

Comment: Be very careful about using double for currency.  The double data type has no exact representation for 0.01 or 0.001 or, for many different multiples of those numbers.  Generally any number that represents an amount of money should be an integer.  E.g., instead of 5.33 dollars, you want to be working with 533 pennies.  Use double only for conversion rates, and immediately convert the result back to an integer number of pennies (or whatever).

Comment: Aside from the fact that you should be using `BigDecimal` or `long`, you haven't told us specifically what your problem is, just that you're struggling and you're having an issue.  That isn't good enough for us to provide help.

Comment: Is there any way you could show me some examples using my code. I figure if I know the correct way to approach this type of program I can use it to build on my skill set. Sorry for asking for so much but it'd be greatly appreciated. I'm feeling pretty lost at this point. I'd hate to ask for a sample program that does the same thing as this but that'd be great.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldn't be converting from `double`s to `int`s, as you will lose the amount after the decimal point. e.g.

```
double num = 1.9;
int number = (int) num;
System.out.println(number);
```

will print

```
1
```

Also, if you do

```
System.out.println(num % 1);
```

you get

```
0.8999999999999999 // not quite 0.9, which is what you were expecting
```

As @Laf pointed out, use `BigDecimal` instead.

```
BigDecimal SEK_CONVERSION_RATE = new BigDecimal(".14");
String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
// Better precision constructing from a String
BigDecimal userCurrencyInput = new BigDecimal(userInput);

BigDecimal calculatedCurrInput = userCurrencyInput.multiply(SEK_CONVERSTION_RATE);
```

Hopefully you can work out the rest from there.

Hint: `BigDecimal` has a method `divideAndRemainder()` which returns a `BigDecimal[]`, where the first part is the quotient, and the second part is the remainder.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divideAndRemainder%28java.math.BigDecimal%29

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `int`s?